# Is it possible to have versioned many_many relations?

Tags: silverstripe

I already used versioning on `DataObjects` when they contain a lot of content, now I'm wondering if it's possible to apply versioning to a `many_many` relation?

Assuming I have the following:

```
class Page extends SiteTree
{
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Images' => 'Image' 
    );
}
```

Then the ORM will create a `Page_Images` table for me to store the relations. In order to have a versioned relation, more tables would be required (eg. `Page_Images_Live`).

Is there any way to tell the ORM to create versioned relations? When looking at the above example with a `Page * – * Images` relation, I *don't* want the `Image` class to be versioned, but rather the relation. Eg. something like this:

```
Version Stage:
---
    PageA
        Images ( ImageA, ImageB, ImageC )

Version Live:
---
    PageA
        Images ( ImageA, ImageC, ImageD, ImageE )
```

Is that even possible out of the box?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this out of the box. Perhaps add a "Published" extra field to the relationship, set that to true when publishing, and filter by it depending on the current stage?

Comment: @ajshort Hm clever idea. It won't be so easy when there are other relation attributes though (something like `SortOrder` which would also change from Stage to Live).

Comment: I know this question is a little old but just to clarify, every version of Page essentially has its own many_many mapping to various Images? Off the top of my head, it could be possible but it isn't easy out-of-the-box. If this is SS3, it could require `GridField` changes to correctly unhook relations for that particular version (instead of all versions).

Comment: @Turnerj yes, that's basically it. Each version will have its own set of images. And yes, the question is about SS3. I'd gladly upvote/accept a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've spent a lot of time looking into this and without fundamentally modifying [`ManyManyList`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-ManyManyList.html) (as it doesn't expose the necessary hooks through the extension system), there isn't many choices.

#### I am a dessert-first kind of person, how CAN we do it?

My only suggestion to accomplish this feat is essentially a many-to-many bridge object (ie. a separate entity joining `Page` and `Image`) via `$has_many` though it still requires quite a bit of modification.

This is [partially discussed on the forum](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/customising-the-cms/show/19737) where a solution about subverting the actual relationship by storing the versioned items against the actual object rather than in a joining table. That would work but I think we can still do better than that.

I am personally leaning towards tying the version of the relationship to the `Page` itself and my partial solution below covers this. Read below the fold for more info trying this as an update to `ManyManyList`.

Something like this is a start:

```
class PageImageVersion extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Version' => 'Int'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Page' => 'Page',
        'Image' => 'Image'
    );
}
```

This contains our 2-way relationship plus we have our version number stored. You will want to specify the `getCMSFields` function to add the right fields required allowing you to relate it to an existing image or upload a new one. I am avoiding covering this as it should be relatively straight forward compared to the actual version handling part.

Now, we have a `has_many` on `Page` like so:

```
private static $has_many = array(
    'Images' => 'PageImageVersion' 
);
```

In my tests, I also added an extension for `Image` adding the matching `$has_many` onto it as well like so:

```
class ImageExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $has_many = array(
        'Pages' => 'PageImageVersion'
    );
}
```

> Honestly, not sure if this is necessary beyond adding the `Pages`
>   function on the `Image` side of the relationship. As far as I can see, it won't really matter for this particular usecase.

Unfortunately, because of this way of versioning, we can't use the standard way of calling the `Images`, we will need to be a bit creative. Something like this:

```
public function getVersionedImages($Version = null)
{
    if ($Version == null)
    {
        $Version = $this->Version;
    }
    else if ($Version < 0)
    {
        $Version = max($this->Version - $Version, 1);
    }

    return $this->Images()->filter(array('Version' => $Version));
}
```

When you call `getVersionedImages()`, it will return all images that have the `Version` set on it aligning with the version of the current page. Also supports getting previous versions via `getVersionedImages(-1)` for the last version or even gets images for a specific version of the page by passing any position number.

OK, so far so good. We now need to make sure that every page write we are getting a duplicate list of images for this new version of the page.

With an `onAfterWrite` function on `Page`, we can do this:

```
public function onAfterWrite()
{
    $lastVersionImages = $this->getVersionedImages(-1);
    foreach ($lastVersionImages as $image)
    {
        $duplicate = $image->duplicate(false);
        $duplicate->Version = $this->Version;
        $duplicate->write();
    }
}
```

> For those playing at home, this is where things get a bit iffy relating to how restoring previous versions of `Page` would affect this.

Because we would be editing this in [`GridField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-GridField.html), we will need to do a few things. First is make sure our code can handle the `Add New` function.

My idea is an `onAfterWrite` on the `PageImageVersion` object:

```
public function onAfterWrite()
{
    //Make sure the version is actually saved
    if ($this->Version == 0)
    {
        $this->Version = $this->Page()->Version;
        $this->write();
    }
}
```

To get your versioned items displaying in `GridField`, you would have it set up similar to this:

```
$gridFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();
$gridField = new GridField("Images", "Images", $this->getVersionedImages(), $gridFieldConfig);
$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Images", $gridField);
```

You might want to link to images directly from the `GridField` via `GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor` however this is when things get sour.

#### Time for the veggies...

One of the big difficulties is `GridField`, for both linking and unlinking these entities. Using the standard `GridFieldDeleteAction` will directly update the relationship without the right version.

You will need to extend `GridFieldDeleteAction` and override the `handleAction` to write your `Page` object (to trigger another version), duplicate every version of our versioned image object for the last version while making it skip the one you don't want in the new version.

> I'll admit, this last bit is just guesswork by me. From my understanding and debugging, it should work but simply there is a lot of fiddling to get it right.

Your extension of `GridFieldDeleteAction` then needs to be added to your specific `GridField`.

This would essentially be your last step away from making this solution work. Once you have the adding, removing, duplicating, version updating part down, it really is a matter of just using `getVersionedImages()` to get the right images.

#### Conclusion

**Avoid.** I get why you want to do this but I really don't see a clean way of being able to handle this without a decent sized update to how `many_many` relationships are handled in Silverstripe.

---

#### But I really want it as a `ManyManyList`!

The changes I see required for `ManyManyList` are having a 3-way key (Foreign Key, Local Key, Version Key) and the various methods for adding/removing/fetching etc updated.

If there were hooks in the `add` and `remove` functions, you might be able to sneak in the functionality as an extension (via Silverstripe's extension system) and add the needed data to the extra fields that `many_many` relationships allow.

While I *could* get this happening by extending `ManyManyList` directly and then forcing `ManyManyList` to be replaced with my custom class via [`Object::useCustomClass`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Object.html#_useCustomClass), it would be even more of a messy solution.

It is simply too long/complex for me to give a full answer for a pure `ManyManyList` solution at this stage (though I may get back to this later and give it a shot).

---

*Disclaimer: I am not a Silverstripe Core dev, there may be a neater solution to this entire thing but I simply can't see how.*

Comment: Wow! Thanks for putting so much work and effort into your answer, much appreciated. Your first approach works, it would require a new approach to editing the images though. Using the UploadField directly to upload several images wouldn't work then... but thinking about it: Leveraging `$many_many_extraFields` to store the version information and using your `onAfterWrite` hook and a similar getter might work even without your intermediate DataObject.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I might have a look into combining the `$many_many_extraFields` with the `onAfterWrite` and see what happens. :)

Comment: @bummzack, how were you intending on editing the `many_many` relationship to upload several images? Using GridField back in your original example just allows adding one image at a time unless I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: what original example are you referring to? You can add multiple images to a `many_many` relation directly via `UploadField`

Comment: Ahhhh OK. I guess to solve the issue you mentioned in your first comment about not being able to upload several images directly via the `UploadField`, you could use the [GridFieldBulkEditingTools](https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldBulkEditingTools) module which supports multi-image upload that can set the upload images against other data objects like my example above. Regarding the extra fields and version number in that, I thought about it more and it will require a lot of special handling, potentially more handling than my suggestion above.

Answer (score 1):

You can define second relation with "_Live" suffix and update it when the page is published. Note: This solution stores only two versions (live and stage).

Bellow is my implementation which automatically detects whether many-many relation is versioned or not. It then handles publishing and data retrieval. All what is needed is to define one extra many-many relation with "_Live" suffix.

$page->Images() returns items according to the current stage (stage/live).

```php
class Page extends SiteTree
{
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Images' => 'Image',
        'Images_Live' => 'Image'
    );

    public function publish($fromStage, $toStage, $createNewVersion = false)
    {
        if ($toStage == 'Live')
        {
            $this->publishManyToManyComponents();
        }

        parent::publish($fromStage, $toStage, $createNewVersion);
    }

    protected function publishManyToManyComponents()
    {
        foreach (static::getVersionedManyManyComponentNames() as $component_name)
        {
            $this->publishManyToManyComponent($component_name);
        }
    }

    protected function publishManyToManyComponent($component_name)
    {
        $stage = $this->getManyManyComponents($component_name);
        $live = $this->getManyManyComponents("{$component_name}_Live");

        $live_table = $live->getJoinTable();
        $live_fk = $live->getForeignKey();
        $live_lk = $live->getLocalKey();

        $stage_table = $stage->getJoinTable();
        $stage_fk = $live->getForeignKey();
        $stage_lk = $live->getLocalKey();

        // update or add items from stage to live
        foreach ($stage as $item)
        {
            $live->add($item, $stage->getExtraData(null, $item->ID));
        }

        // delete remaining items from live table
        DB::query("DELETE l FROM $live_table AS l LEFT JOIN $stage_table AS s ON l.$live_fk = s.$stage_fk AND l.$live_lk = s.$stage_lk WHERE s.ID IS NULL");

        // update new items IDs in live table (IDs are incremental so the new records can only have higher IDs than items in ID => should not cause duplicate IDs)
        DB::query("UPDATE $live_table AS l INNER JOIN $stage_table AS s ON l.$live_fk = s.$stage_fk AND l.$live_lk = s.$stage_lk SET l.ID = s.ID WHERE l.ID != s.ID;");
    }

    public function manyManyComponent($component_name)
    {
        if (Versioned::current_stage() == 'Live' && static::isVersionedManyManyComponent($component_name))
        {
            return parent::manyManyComponent("{$component_name}_Live");
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::manyManyComponent($component_name);
        }
    }

    protected static function isVersionedManyManyComponent($component_name)
    {
        $many_many_components = (array) Config::inst()->get(static::class, 'many_many', Config::INHERITED);
        return isset($many_many_components[$component_name]) && isset($many_many_components["{$component_name}_Live"]);
    }

    protected static function getVersionedManyManyComponentNames()
    {
        $many_many_components = (array) Config::inst()->get(static::class, 'many_many', Config::INHERITED);

        foreach ($many_many_components as $component_name => $dummy)
        {
            $is_live = 0;

            $stage_component_name = preg_replace('/_Live$/', '', $component_name, -1, $is_live);

            if ($is_live > 0 && isset($many_many_components[$stage_component_name]))
            {
                yield $stage_component_name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about making this more generic and turning it into a module? Could be useful…